# What to resources to read to import Excel data to AutoCAD?

Tags: excel, resources, autocad

Doing some preliminary work on a project.  I work at an engineering firm and the engineers build Excel spreadsheets containing information on what material the project uses (called cable schedules).  This data is handed over to the drafter and they turn it into an AutoCAD drawing.  If a change in the spreadsheet gets made the drafter needs to meticulously change every drawing.  This is supposedly a lot of manual work.

I know little of AutoCAD and was wondering what research I should do to see if and how hard it would be to automate this process.  If a course or books are available I'd like to be pointed in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to simply display some Excel data as a table in AutoCAD the functionality is already built in via AutoCAD's [DATALINK](http://exchange.autodesk.com/autocad/enu/online-help/browse#WS1a9193826455f5ffa23ce210c875431153025.htm) command.

If you want to automate something more complicated than that check out Autodesk's [ObjectARX](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=773204). It's used to create AutoCAD plugins and can be downloaded for free from their website. ObjectARX exposes both .NET and native C++ APIs. It is the library that AutoCAD itself is based on.

The RealDWG API (formally ObjectDBX) that Chris Neilsen mentioned is a subset of the functionality available in ObjectARX. It allows you to read and manipulate AutoCAD drawings outside of an AutoCAD process. RealDWG is, however, not free.

As for documentation, the help files and samples included with ObjectARX are pretty good and there is a fair amount of programming discussion on the Autodesk and AUGI forums. If your employer is an ADN member you'll find a lot more information there, including professional support.

Answer (score 0):

See this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/169390/445425) for a discussion of libraries to access drawing files, including [ODA](http://www.opendesign.com/) and 
[AutoDesk RealDWG](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=770257) and a few others

Answer (score 0):

The library I use for manipulating Excel from AutoCAD is available as a download here:

http://download.cnet.com/KozMos-VLXLS/3000-2077_4-94214.html

I found it far easier to use this inside the VLIDE to manipulate Excel data (whether it has anything to do with AutoCAD or not), than to use Excel's VBA (a horror) or a combination of scripting and interop.

I did have to fix one or two mistakes in there, so bear that in mind...